# Git log only master branch

Tags: git, branch, git-commit, git-log

### Is there any way to display in git log only commits, which have been ever pointed by master branch?

*For example:*

```
*   c7e0107 - (22 hours ago) Merge branch 'branch_b' - MASTER
|\
| *   3b90496 - (22 hours ago) Merge branch 'branch_a' into branch_b -
| |\
| * | 033fef1 - (22 hours ago) _____________ -
| * | 29449c6 - (22 hours ago) _____________ - 
* | |   cbd8a15 - (22 hours ago) Merge branch 'branch_a' - MASTER
|\ \ \
| | |/
| |/|
| * | e5e4aa4 - (22 hours ago) _____________ - 
| * | 7215282 - (22 hours ago) _____________ - 
| * | e9aadd9 - (22 hours ago) _____________ - 
| * | 4824cef - (22 hours ago) _____________ - 
* | | 4a13ff3 - (22 hours ago) _____________ - MASTER
| |/
|/|
* | 77b9965 - (22 hours ago) _____________ - MASTER
* | 47fef00 - (22 hours ago) _____________ - MASTER
|/
* 2cd1c2e - (22 hours ago) _____________ - MASTER
* 768ebc8 - (22 hours ago) _____________ - MASTER
```

And I would like to display only commits described as 'MASTER'. I notice that '--first-parent' option or 'git cherry -v master' doesn't work. I can't also do it from graph because often master branch isn't on the leftmost side.

Comment: That is what `git log` shows, when you run it while on `master` branch. It will show all the commits that are reachable from HEAD.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. The log you are showing to us is exactly what you want: it shows only commit reachable from the master branch.

Comment: I want to extract the main product path to a report. For example, 'master branch (pointer)' has never pointed to commit 3b90496 <--- this is feature branch, so i don't want to include its in my report. Simply, I would like to extract "master branch" (main path) from graph of commits.

Answer (score 0):

`--first-parent` option should do the trick

Comment: --first-parent as the name suggest takes first parents, so if somebody merge master into any other branch X, first parent of this commit will be exactly commit from branch X. And this means that it displays commit from feature branch X intead of master as well as this merge commit. However, I've written in question, that --first-parent doesn't work.